# Remove all HTMLtags in a string (with the jquery text() function)

Tags: jquery, string, text

is it possible to use the jquery text() function to remove all HTML in a string?

**String with HTML tags:**
`myContent = '<div id="test">Hello <span>world!</span></div>';`

**The result must be:**
 `Hello world!`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strip HTML from Text JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/822452/strip-html-from-text-javascript)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50989976/how-to-find-a-htmltag-in-a-string-using-jquery-javascript

Answer (score 98, accepted):

```
var myContent = '<div id="test">Hello <span>world!</span></div>';

alert($(myContent).text());
```

That results in hello world. Does that answer your question?

http://jsfiddle.net/D2tEf/ for an example

Comment: Or to put this another way, for any string value of x, $('<span>'+x+'</span>').text() == x always evaluates to true.

Comment: Actually its not true, if the string contains html.

Comment: This solution works only if myContent is a true HTML string, to generalize the solution I think it's better use:
stringClean=$("<div>"+myContent+"</div>").text();

Comment: As @AlessandroBattistini pointed out, `$(myContent)` will fail if myContent doesn't happen to be a true HTML string -- `$("<div>"+myContent+"</div>")` ensures this will never be an issue and thus, the better answer here.

Answer (score 39):

I created this test case: http://jsfiddle.net/ccQnK/1/ , I used the Javascript replace function with regular expressions to get the results that you want.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var myContent = '<div id="test">Hello <span>world!</span></div>';
    alert(myContent.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,""));
});
```

Comment: You should always post the actual solution here, not just in jsfiddle or some similar site. There is no guarantee that the other site will be around in the future.

Comment: from jsfiddle myContent.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"")

Comment: Not a big fan of regex solutions. They can almost always be broken.

Comment: This will remove text like `<3 love ya <br />` completelly

Answer (score 26):

If you need to remove the HTML but does not know if it actually contains any HTML tags, you can't use the jQuery method directly because it returns empty wrapper for non-HTML text.

```
$('<div>Hello world</div>').text(); //returns "Hello world"
$('Hello world').text(); //returns empty string ""
```

You must either wrap the text in valid HTML:

```
$('<div>' + 'Hello world' + '</div>').text();
```

Or use method $.parseHTML() (since jQuery 1.8) that can handle both HTML and non-HTML text:

```
var html = $.parseHTML('Hello world'); //parseHTML return HTMLCollection
var text = $(html).text(); //use $() to get .text() method
```

Plus parseHTML removes script tags completely which is useful as anti-hacking protection for user inputs.

```
$('<p>Hello world</p><script>console.log(document.cookie)</script>').text();
//returns "Hello worldconsole.log(document.cookie)"

$($.parseHTML('<p>Hello world</p><script>console.log(document.cookie)</script>')).text();
//returns "Hello world"
```

Answer (score 9):

Another option:

```js
 $("<p>").html(myContent).text();
```

Answer (score 7):

Could you not just [try it](http://jsfiddle.net/7eGtx/2/)?

```
myContent = '<div id="test">Hello <span>world!</span></div>';
console.log($(myContent).text()); //Prints "Hello world!"
```

Note that you need to wrap the string in a jQuery object, otherwise it won't have a `text` method obviously.

Answer (score 3):

I found in my specific case that I just needed to trim the content. Maybe not the answer asked in the question. But I thought I should add this answer anyway.

```
$(myContent).text().trim()
```