# Remove HTMLtags with text enclosed into them

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Using jquery text() function to remove all HTML tags in a string?

**I have HTML string like this:**
`myContent = '<div id="test">Hello <span>world!</span></div>';`

**I want to generate output from jquery like this:**
 `Hello`

I have checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7889765/631652) question but can not find my answer. Please let me know if its duplicate of any other question.

Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `$(myContent).find('span').remove().end().text()`

Comment: @Satpal.. this will remove the span element from DOM

Comment: Ah, I thought you were getting the value form DOM...My bad ..

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/LjzLtyLe/

Comment: @Runcorn.. I thought that too.. in this case satpal is correct

Comment: Thank you guys for your help. @Satpal thank you dear for quick one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like

```
var myContent = '<div id="test">Hello <span>world!</span></div>';

var $tmp = $(myContent);
myContent = $tmp.contents().filter(function () {
    return this.nodeType == 3;
}).text();

console.log(myContent)
```

---

Another way is

```
var myContent = '<div id="test">Hello <span>world!</span></div>';

var $tmp = $(myContent);
$tmp.find('*').remove();
myContent = $tmp.text();
```

Answer (score 1):

If the element is a dom element on the page, then this solution is effective. A simple solution.  http://jsfiddle.net/u60b2fn1/1/

```
 $(function(){
   var str= $('#test').text()
    str = str.replace($('span').text(), "");
   alert(str );

});
```

If there is a string like: 
 `var myContent = '<div id="test">Hello <span>world!</span></div>';`
Then satpal has already answered this in the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/LjzLtyLe/)

Comment: Thanks! got idea from this!

Answer (score 0):

```
var myContent = '<div id="test">Hello <span>world!</span></div>';

alert($(myContent).text());
```

OR you can Use IT this way also

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var myContent = '<div id="test">Hello <span>world!</span></div>';
    alert(myContent.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,""));
});
```

Comment: This is not working. Why people up-vote such non working answers!