# How to find a htmltag in a string using jquery/javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, .net, tags

I have a text area in a page. If user try to give some html tags as a input and submit then i need to throw an error.

How can i get this done using jquery/javascript?

Could anyone please help me with this ?

Comment: Why throw an error when you can escape the tags? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6234773/can-i-escape-html-special-chars-in-javascript

Comment: Basically that is my requirement. I can let the user enter only the text. So when they input html tag i should throw an error message.

Comment: It's better to perform a whitelist instead of a blacklist

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if a string is html or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15458876/check-if-a-string-is-html-or-not)

Comment: read @dfsq answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15458968/1248177)

Comment: @aloisdg the reply given by dfsq is not validating <html>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reply given in the above comment is not considering below html tags.

```
<html>,<body> and <head>
```

So this is how i implemented the requirement and it is working fine.

```
var textboxValue = document.getElementById("textbox").value;
var nonHtmlValue = textboxValue.replace(/<[^>]+>/g, '');
if(textboxValue!=nonHtmlValue)
{
    alert("HTML is not allowed");
}
```