# Get text out of node HTML in Variable Text Given

Tags: javascript, jquery, text

I have this variable in javascript:

```
var datos = '<input type="hidden" name="i_txt_Prod_Code" value="Foo_Bar" tabindex="1">01080';
```

I need get the text `01080` from this, ignoring the hidden `input` or any other `input` tag.

```
var text = data.text(); //I used this but it did not work

if (data.match("<input")) {
  var datos = $(data);
  datos.find("input[type=hidden]").each(function(index) {
    $(this).remove();
  });
  data = datos.html();
}
```

**not duplicated @HereticMonkey pls read the post first. i am using jquery no javascript pure. o EMC structure.**

Comment: Why can you not use the hidden `input`? If the `value` of that always matches the text you want to retrieve, it would be far easier to just read it from there.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan becouse They do not always coincide; What I need is to resolve the doubt, not do something different.

Comment: In which case giving them the same value in the question is confusing matters. I've edited the question to remove that `value`. In any case, see my answer below

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Strip HTML from Text JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822452/strip-html-from-text-javascript)

Comment: not duplicated @HereticMonkey pls read the post first. i am using jquery no javascript pure. o EMC structure.

Comment: jQuery is written in JavaScript. You can use the code in jQuery without altering it. I have no idea what "EMC structure" means; it's not mentioned in the question.

Comment: Okay, it took a few seconds, but [here's a duplicate that uses jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7889765/215552).

Comment: @HereticMonkey you're going off on a tangent ... I did not say I want to remove the html tag, I did not say I want to get the text inside a tag ... you are changing the meaning of my question to your personal criteria and looking for the fifth leg to the cat .... the question is very simple: "Get text out of node HTML in Variable Text Given"; is not Exactly what other people ask ...

Comment: I'm reading your question as it is and I'm not examining any cats. You're asking "get text out of a string of HTML" Just because you're not specifically saying "remove the HTML tag" is irrelevant. Would you accept an answer where the result still had the HTML tag? No. The answers to both questions I've shown are exactly the same as @RoryMcCrossan's accepted answer of this question.

Comment: "Get text out of node HTML in Variable Text Given" not is equal to that you see/read: "get text out of a string of HTML"; your examples are not the same or similar: the first: search for text with pure javascript inside a tag; you asked me if I would accept something like that, you are changing from that point the question to your own criteria, which I hope in jquery format; it is as if someone asked something of angular.js and you said it is duplicated because the answer is in node.js ... second answer: it is even worse, look for text inside the html tag already in the variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you cannot access the `input`, for whatever reason, the simplest way to achieve what you require would be to create a jQuery object which is a `div` that contains the HTML you have in the `datos` variable. Then you can simply call `text()` on this `div`:

```js
var datos = '<input type="hidden" name="i_txt_Prod_Code_01080" value="01080" tabindex="1">01080';

var $datos = $('<div>' + datos + '</div>');
console.log($datos.text());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```