# Jquery – html in text()?

Tags: jquery

I've got a simple chat script that I'm using on my site. I'm using the text() to sanitize the message name and content so users can't include HTML and introduce madness, but I need the msg.name to be a clickable 
link: 
Something like this:

```
'[<a href="/users/?id=' + msg.user_id + '</a>]'
```

But I can't use html() because it'll expose the msg.content. I've tried doing something like this but have had no luck:

```
$('<li/>').html().text(.....`
```

```js
if (msg.id > last_message_id) {
  var date = new Date(msg.time * 1000);
  $('<li/>').text('[' + msg.name + '] ' + msg.content+ ' ').appendTo('ul#messages');
  $('ul#messages').data('last_message_id', msg.id);
}
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Remove the HTML from the user input, ([like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7889765/remove-all-htmltags-in-a-string-with-the-jquery-text-function)) then use `html()` to update the DOM including your `a` element

Comment: That being said, I assume if this is a chat system you're using server side websockets, in which case you should do the sanitisation there and return the cleansed message to the UI.

Comment: Add the message in a span and concatenate the link

Comment: I like that idea....How would I sanitize this:     
var content =  $("#content").val();