# How can I stop form submission in tinyMCE if it contains whitespaces only?

Tags: jquery, tinymce

I have integrated TinyMCE editor into my code (PHP code). I have a form in my php file and in that form, I have a textarea (integrated with editor) only.
Now the problem is that if I enter more than 1 space in my text editor (without entering any characters) So the form is submitted.And when I do console.log() it returns the HTML like -

```
<p>&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
```

So now, I want to restrict this kind of form if it contains spaces only, how can I do that?

Comment: i think this may hold the key to the answer for you  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7889765/remove-all-htmltags-in-a-string-with-the-jquery-text-function

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to adapt this answer to your own needs, but basically you can let the DOM do the work.  I've set your `<p>` string inside two `div`s (the second modified to contain a character) and set the onclick event to do a regex test for whitespace which uses the `textContent` property to strip out/convert the html to text only.

```js
function checkws(evt) {
  document
    .getElementById('results')
    .innerText = `${evt.currentTarget.id} is only whitespace: \
    ${/^\s*$/.test(evt.currentTarget.textContent)}`;

}
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin: 8px;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="tinymce1" onclick="checkws(event)">
  <p>&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
</div>

<div id="tinymce2" onclick="checkws(event)">
  <p>&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; X</p>
</div>

<div id="results">Click a div above</div>
```